# Android IntentService calls toast that does not stop itself

Tags: android

I messed with the  example from the android website on services. The service is meant to call a toast. I start the service using a button's onClick method.  It works but the toast never ends! I thought IntentService specifically stops itself after the process is complete.

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Enslaved extends IntentService {
     public Enslaved() {
        super("Enslaved");
     }


     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Starting service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did that once too, it made me feel really silly...

You can save a reference to the Toast and cancel it in `onDestroy()`. Or just not interact with the UI in such a short lived service.

```
Toast toast;

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Starting service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    toast.cancel();
}
```